# Remove "BESbewy" from google API

Tags: google-api

How to remove "BESbewy" from google API so that there would be no excessive horizontal scroll bar ? Or at least how is it possible to remove the property "left -999" ?

Answer (score 0):

Not the best way to do it but it has a small performance compact and more important, it works:

```
var clearDamnSpan = setInterval(function () {
  $('body > span').each(function () {
    if ($(this).text() === 'BESbewy') {
      //if you remove the element, You might see errors in Google Chrome
      $(this).hide();
      clearInterval(clearDamnSpan);
    }
  });
}, 500);
setTimeout(function () {
  clearInterval(clearDamnSpan);
}, 50000);
```